# ahref ../ directory not working as intended

Tags: node.js, hyperlink, directory

So currently I'm using nodejs express , serving a simple webpage.

Right now I am trying to use a href to link to a source outside of my current folder, using ../. However, it seems that I am unable to go out of my "app" folder.
Below is the structure of my file directory

```
App
-> index.html
-> route.js
Another Folder
-> Another Folder
    -> Resource1.jpg
```

I have tried using

```
<a href="../Another Folder/Another Folder/Resource.jpg"></a>
```

but it does not work.
Is there something wrong with my path or it is just not possible to locate a resource outside of App folder?

Comment: Are you trying to load an image to your page ?

Comment: My resource is currently a .pdf file

Answer (score 0):

If you try loading image in your page then try this path with **img** tag or if your file is pdf then rename it to **file.pdf** try other wise no idea because of no error in your script :)